# Constructing a function over a metric space through given points

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, mg.metric-geometry, norms

Suppose there is a compact metric space $(X,\rho)$ and a Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$.

There is a sequence of unequal points $\{x_1,...x_N\}$ in $X$ such that all metrics $\rho(x_i,x_j)$ are known and $f(x_i)=a_i$ for some $a_i$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ whereas:

$$ \forall x_i,x_j \in \{x_1,...x_N\} . ||a_i-a_j|| \leq L \cdot \rho(x_i, x_j) $$

for a fixed $L$.

Suppose also that $\{x_1,...x_N\}$ form a finite cover of $X$ by balls of some suitable (known) radius.

If $X$ were just a compact interval, $\{x_1,...x_N\}$ its partition, and $n$ were $1$, we could certainly construct a piecewise-linear function $f:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ such that:

$$ f(x_i)=a_i \\ \forall x,y \in X . ||f(x)-f(y)|| \leq L \cdot \rho(x, y) $$

with a slope controlled by $L$.

It should be also possible in certain cases if $X \subset \mathbb{R}^m$.

**Is it possible to construct such a function for a general compact metric space? And if $X$ is a subset of a Euclidean space?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Applying rescaling you can assume that $L=1$.

We look for a 1-Lipschitz piecewise linear maps $f\colon\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^n$.

If $m=n$ we get $f$ from Brehm's theorem;
it says that there is a piecewise distance preserving map of that type (in particular 1-Lipschitz and piecewise linear). 
See Brehm, U., *Extensions of distance reducing mappings to piecewise
congruent mappings on $\mathbb{R}^m$* and also [our paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1405.6606) written for kids.

If $m<n$ we can think that $\mathbb{R}^m$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$; in this case apply Brehm's theorem and restrict the obtained map to $\mathbb{R}^m$.

If $m>n$ we can think that $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^m$; in this case apply Brehm's theorem and compose the obtained map with the projection to $\mathbb{R}^n$.
Since projection linear and 1-Lipschitz, so it the composition.

Comment: Dear Anton, do you have anywhere an illustration on how to actually fold a sheet of paper to match the "dots" according to your or Brehm's proofs? It feels like it's possible to give a counter-example, where all points are matched, except for just one, the distances are not stretched and there is no way to fold a paper to match the last dot.

Comment: @RubiShnol I do not understand your question. But for sure Brehm's proof is correct. If you locate problematic part in our notes, then I will try to help.

Comment: Consider the following: take a sheet of paper with a square on it with numbered vertices. Move two of them inwards and one slightly outwards. Suppose the target positions are matched (there was a PW isometry built), except for the last vertex which gotta be matched with the target that "moved" outward. There seems to be no PW isometry that could match the last vertex without distracting the map already built in the previous step.

Comment: @RubiShnol I did not get it --- try to read the proof.

Comment: I sketched the example [here](https://postimg.cc/NKZtSPX8). I studied the proofs but somehow always failed to extract a working algorithm off of them.

Comment: @RubiShnol, OK, but this claim does not contradict Brehm's theorem --- you look for a map with additional properties.

Comment: I don't think I'm looking for a map with any additional properties relative to Brehm. The theorem is about piece-wise congruent extensions. The same applies to my example. It totally satisfies the conditions of the theorem, yet no PW congruent map can be constructed by extension, at least not in any inductive manner.

Comment: @RubiShnol extension means from finite set to the whole space (not more than that).

Comment: Exactly. There is a map $f$ from a finite subset of $R^2$ to $R^2$ that is non-extending. We are trying to extend it to the whole space. Suppose, a map $\psi$ on the whole $R^2$ was constructed. We are looking for some $\phi$ to combine with $\psi$, in fact,  PW isometry. I claim that can't be done in the example given. The task satisfied the conditions of the Brehm's theorem, I stress. The map could be constructed, but not in the Brehm's inductive manner

Comment: @RubiShnol, no, just follow the proof, and you will see the map.

Comment: Let me explain. [Here](https://i.postimg.cc/prTVjtMk/Cam-Scanner-03-05-2024-19-07-page-0001.jpg) is an example following the proof in your lecture notes. The last step where you extend $f$ in the blind zone is problematic. You can't match $a_3$ with $b_3$, while preserving $E$, AND the distances on $\mathbb R^2$ AND not touching $a_2$ which was already mapped correctly by $h$. You can do some tricks to rematch $a_2$, but that'd distract the inductive manner of the construction.

Comment: @RubiShnol, blind zone creates no problem: notice that the same proof works on the sphere and in the sphere there is no blind zone. You get the statement for Euclidean space as well since it cn be approximated by spheres --- the lecture notes decribe another proof which is also correct (and the same holds for the original proof of Brehm).

Comment: Anton, sorry to bother but look: the example given satisfies the conditions of Theorem 2.1 in your lectures note. The construction shown follows precisely the proof. At the last step, there is simply NO modification of $h$ that matches $a_3$ and leaves other already matched points intact unless it "rips" the space whence it's not $1-$Lip. Maybe, you mean the overall map need not be continuous, but merely PW continuous (in fact, congruent)?

Comment: @RubiShnol I do not see a problem in your example. The picture you sent me does not show $\Omega$, so let's make sure: it is a pentagon made from three triangles with vertex $a_3$, first is green based on the crease line under $i$, after that red (blind) with base inside $[a_1a_2]$ and the last one is green again its base inside $\tau_2$ --- do you agree?

Comment: I made a crisper [picture](https://i.postimg.cc/B67Bb2Zv/Brehm.png). $\Omega$ is everything in $A$ above the $E$ line. $h$ acts as reflections on $\tau_2, \tau_4$ and as identity otherwise (legit choice). $a_3$ is to be matched with $b_3$. $T$ is chosen according to the proof. $\dot \imath$ is the isometry which happens to be a reflection around $E$ to meet the requirements in the proof. Now, seemingly, $a_3$ is matched with $b_3$. There is no way to complete $f$ in the blind zone ("framed" by $Z$) without ripping the space or "unmatching" the already matched $a_2$.

Comment: @RubiShnol Impressive picture, suppose $x$ is the intersection point of $[a_1a_2]$ with the red line. Then $|a_3-x|=|b_3-x|$. Since you $\Omega$ is everything above the red line we also have $|a_3-a_2|=|b_3-b_2|$. Since $x$ is fixed by $h$, we also $|b_2-x|\le |a_2-x|$, so we can fold the blind zone along a line thru $a_3$ so that after folding these distances are equal --- this fold fits the remaining part ot the map.

Comment: Well, but $a_2$ was already mapped to $b_2$ by $h$! In this case, you can't fold the blind zone the required way. Sure, if $a_2$ were YET to be fitted, we could fold the blind zone to match BOTH $a_2$ and $a_3$ with their respective targets, but that ruins the proof by induction. If we are allowed to somehow "undo" the action of $h$ in the blind zone, then it also points towards reconsidering the proof construction, because my example is simple, but the situation may be way more difficult.

Comment: @RubiShnol in the induction hypothesis we assumed there is a PL map for $n-1$ points and produce a PL that match $n$ points --- what is ruined? And by the way it is exactly the argument in the leccture notes --- see exercise 2.2 and its solution on page 52.

Comment: Why not to apply this non-inductive construction in the first place? The situation with the blind zone seems no different to the one described in my example. We need practically a similar construction, there may be multiple points inside the blind zone. I was thinking of matching one point at a time without distorting the already matched points. That's probably why I found that inductive construction a bit awkward

Comment: Btw, $|a_3-a_2|$ needs not be equal to $|b_3-b_2|$ and the fold around $E$ to match $a_3$ with $b_3$ needs not to simultaneously match $a_2$ with $b_2$. I still find the construction really awkward. After the required fold to match $a_3$ and $b_3$, the point $a_2$ (say, after we "undo" its matching via $h$ with $b_2$ by our inductive construction) gets far away from $b_2$. Not saying it can't be rematched, but it doesn't seem to fit Ex. 2.2

Comment: If $|a_3-a_2|\ne|b_3-b_2|$, then $\Omega$ is not everything above $E$ (you claimed opposite).

Comment: But that doesn't change much. We have a polygon $Q$ formed by $x$ (the intersection of $[a_1, a_2]$ with $E$), $a_2$ and $a_3$. First of all, why should I assume $a_3=b_3$ as Ex. 2.2 on p. 52 says? Either $Q$ is as per the proof or something else, because, clearly, it's something else after $\dot \imath$. In fact, we need a map on $Q$ that identifies the whole $[x, a_3]$ with $[x, b_3]$. Could you please clarify how the last claim in the proof (Ex. 2.2) applies here?

Comment: @RubiShnol Let me copy something from p. 52: "These can be arranged by applying a translation, followed by a rotation, and then possibly a reflection."  (BTW, is it all a practical joke?)

Comment: Not at all. You just repeated how to match the $a_3$ point -- that was clear from the start. I am concerned with the points that were once matched and then we discard this part of the $h$. Ex. on p.52 does not (or at least not explicitly) address the points that were already matched. The ex. does not give a recipe on how to rematch the point $a_2$, say. There may be multiple such points, so the Ex. doesn't address this. Moreover, to actually address this, you probably need to repeat the whole inductive construction, hence circularity as it seems.

Comment: @RubiShnol no, $a_1$ plays a special role in $Q$ and it is unique in this sense.

Comment: @RubiShnol (I suspect that you missed something very simple, but I cannot guess what is it. Maybe try to make your example from paper and try to fold it following the construction.)

Comment: @RubiShnol https://postimg.cc/gallery/DWs0FM3

Comment: I already did that with a sheet of paper. It's not hard if we are allowed to "unfold" back some points already folded earlier. I just somehow fail to see an algorithm. That $a_2$ had to be unfolded to rematch again, after we match $a_3$. But that was just $a_2$, there might have been multiple points already matched and then unmatch them. It seems we have to repeat the inductive construction for $Q$, with all the unmatched points in it. What are exactly the $x$ and $y$ points in the proof?

Comment: @RubiShnol, just follow the exercise --- well if you want to do higher dimensions then you should invent something else. One example is the approximation by sphere, another is given in the paper of Brehm.

Comment: Ok, just what are the $x_1, \dots, x_k$ and $y_1, \dots, y_k$ points?

Comment: @RubiShnol --- $x_i$ are vertices on the border of blind zone and A. (In your case there only $x_1$, $x_2$, $y_1$, $y_2$.)

Comment: Thanks, that helps. Finally, do I understand correctly that for each polygon there may be at most one point ($y_k$?) that might need re-matching via fold?

Comment: @RubiShnol yes.

Answer (score 6):

Anton's answer is for the case where $X$ is a subset of a Hilbert space.  For $X$ a general metric space (compactness does not help, BTW), $L$ must be increased by a factor of order $\log^{1/2}N$; see
$$$$
 Johnson, William B.; Lindenstrauss, Joram Extensions of Lipschitz mappings into a Hilbert space. Conference in modern analysis and probability (New Haven, Conn., 1982), 189–206, Contemp. Math., 26, Amer. Math. Soc., Providence, RI, 1984.

Comment: You do not except PL map from general metric space, dont' you?